# Get reference to the document library sharepoint 2013

Tags: development, web

I want to get reference to document library in code using SP 2013 by url, I am trying the SPWeb.GetList(url); but it works for lists only.

any help?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var list = web.Lists["Documents"];
SPDocumentLibrary doclib =   (SPDocumentLibrary)list;
```

Comment: Hi Max, thanks for your response, I want to be able to get the document library by its URL not by its name, as I will have multi lingual site, so the Documents will not work in all languages, I need a way to make this: SPWeb.GetList("/lists/mylist"), but this method works on lists only. Thanks

Comment: You have to know the name apparently - by url it somehow does not work.

Comment: But it's weird there is an API to retrieve it for lists by URL but it doesn't work for libraries? that's strange!

Comment: You could decompile the function and learn why

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: Download ILSpy or DotPeek and open the dll containing SPWeb. Then examine the function.